# Scala: accessing properties using covariant Field[+T]

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, functional-programming, covariance

I'm using a custom immutable entity class which uses keys that are case objects which extends Field[+T] where T is covariant. It makes sense because a Field[Stream[Int]] should be able to be treated as a Field[Seq[Int]].

```
object ProblemWithCovariant {

  sealed trait Field[+T]
  case object _username extends Field[String]
  case object _email extends Field[String]
  case object _age extends Field[Byte]

  case class Entity(attrs: Map[Field[Any], Any]) {
    def apply[T](field: Field[T]): T = attrs(field).asInstanceOf[T]
    def set[T](field: Field[T])(value: T): Entity = copy(attrs = attrs.updated(field, value))
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val user = Entity(Map.empty)
      .set(_username)("John")
      .set(_age)(23)

    val username: String = user(_username) // alright
    val ageInt: Int = user(_age) // compile error
  }

}
```

This however causes a compile error when I try to retrieve a Byte value and assign it to an Int field. I am aware that Byte is not a subtype of Int and their only relation is an implicit conversion. To my surprise, this conversion was not called in the above example and the compiler now demands me to pass a Field[Int]!

After experimenting for a while, I realized I could simply provide the type explicitly, such as `val ageInt: Int = user[Byte](_age)`. Although this works, it makes my code more verbose than I would prefer. Is there any way I can change the signature of `Entity.apply` such that  it respects the type of the `field` parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def apply[T, U](field: Field[U])(implicit ev: U => T): T = 
  ev(attrs(field).asInstanceOf[U])
```

works.

Comment: Dont understand a couple of things. 1. you are using the function `ev` in the method without defining it. How does that work & what is the type T in your solution? 2. Any idea why the numeric widening from byte to int is not occuring in the OP's original code?

Comment: 1. `ev` is a parameter. Just like if you write `def f(x: Int) = ...`, you use `x` without defining it. The types `T` and `U` are different for different calls of `apply`: they are also parameters. But for `val ageInt: Int = user(_age)`, `T` is `Int` and `U` is `Byte`.

Comment: Actually, I was confused which implicit definition was being used in this scope. Didn't know that the compiler is picking up `Predef.$conforms` as `ev` in this case.

Comment: Interesting...this actually works in all my cases, except that when I declare `case object _hobbies extends Field[Seq[String]]` and then `user(_hobbies).foreach(hobby => ...)`, my editor (IntelliJ IDEA) highlights it red and refuses to resolve the `foreach` call even though it compiles fine, but that's not a problem with the language.

Comment: @shingekinolinus - IntelliJ doesn't actually use the production Scala compiler and doesn't understand the full range of Scala. While it's very handy to have error highlighting while coding, you should always treat `scalac` or `sbt compile` as the final arbiter of what is valid Scala.